# Android activity takes too long to load

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity

I have to initialize object of TextTOSpeech API as the ativity is loaded but it takes 4-5 seconds to start activity when I initialize my TTS object.I tried to initialize it in Async Task and Thread but the result is same. How can I make my activity to load faster? Here is the code for my thread that initializes TTS object.

```
     class LoadingThread implements Runnable{
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //load settings of the app
            appSettings = new AppSettings(getApplicationContext());
            appSettings.loadSettings();
            //making ready TTS before the user interact with it
            textToSpeech = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
                @Override
                public void onInit(int status) {
                    ttsOptions = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    ttsOptions.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID,ActivityMain.UTTER_ID);
                    textToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);
                    textToSpeech.setSpeechRate(AppSettings.getSpeakerSpeed());
                }
            });
            textToSpeech.setOnUtteranceCompletedListener(new TextToSpeech.OnUtteranceCompletedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onUtteranceCompleted(String s) {
                    ActivityMain.mNotepad.onStopSpeaker(s);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

I'm calling this thread in onResume() of my activity like

```
LoadingThread thread = new LoadingThread();
        thread.run();
```

Comment: Can you post your entire onCreate please and the XML for the activity.

Comment: Did you try your app  on an real device ?Because the emulator might have that much time to launch .

Comment: @katmanco I'm using my real device not the virtual device

Comment: If it takes that long to load then it takes that long to load. You're not going to change that. But the way to handle it (and according to the Google design guidelines), you should design your Activity in a way that the UI loads quickly and allows the user to interact with it quickly, even if they have to see a progress spinner or something while the TTS api is loading in the background.

Answer (score 0):

The Application `class` is the wrong place to do this. If you want, it's acceptable to use the Application's `onCreate`() method to start a `Service`. You should implement this background thread in a `Service`, as the purpose of `Service` is to do things in the background. The Application `class` should seldom be used. It's a last resort for maintaining minimal amounts of global state.

Once you move this code into a `Service`, `Looper.prepare()` will already have been called for you by Android.

OP was actually trying to create a `Handler` inside of the `Thread` when he invoked the constructor of his `FileManager` class. While my comment above is still true, it is not relevant to OP's question as he was subclassing Activity and not Application.

To be clear, the actual problem was that he was creating a `Handler` inside a Thread which had not yet called `Looper.prepare()` (via new FileManager()). The correct fix would be to create the Handler on the main thread, i.e. in one of the `Activity` or `Service callbacks`.

Answer (score 0):

You start your thread incorrectly, you just call Runnable's run method which executes in a same thread.
If you need to run it in separate thread use:

```
new Thread(new LoadingThread()).start();
```

Also most probably you'll get exception in here, as this needs to run on main thread:

```
ActivityMain.mNotepad.onStopSpeaker(s);
```

you need to use Handler or Activiy.runOnUiThread() method to handle this

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `new Thread(runnable).start()` to run it on a different thread, not `runnable.run()`.